# Convert daily returns to monthly returns in r

Tags: r

We have daily returns from well over 100 mutual funds that we wish to convert into monthly returns. The monthly return should not be the average from each month, but the funds' return at the end of each month. The funds start and end at different points in time, and they need to remain by themself (not adding all mutual fund returns into 1 each month).

As of the picture one may see the dataframe (df) and parts of its content. The dates are in the first column and it needs to be sorted.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgVCD.png)
We would love some help to solve this problem.

I believe that it contains sufficient information be able to write the code.

> ### DATA,dput(df5[1:50,])
>
> 1. "Date"     "Name"     "Nav"
> 2. 2012-01-02 Aktiva 10 121.738
> 3. 2012-01-03 Aktiva 10  121.87
> 4. 2012-01-04 Aktiva 10 121.906
> 5. 2012-01-05 Aktiva 10  121.89
> 6. 2012-01-06 Aktiva 10 121.949
> 7. 2012-01-09 Aktiva 10 122.024
> 8. 2012-01-10 Aktiva 10 122.205
> 9. 2012-01-11 Aktiva 10 122.219
> 10. 2012-01-12 Aktiva 10 122.324
> 11. 2012-01-13 Aktiva 10 122.309
> 12. 2012-01-16 Aktiva 10  122.45
> 13. 2012-01-17 Aktiva 10 122.433
> 14. 2012-01-18 Aktiva 10 122.483
> 15. 2012-01-19 Aktiva 10 122.596
> 16. 2012-01-20 Aktiva 10 122.548
> 17. 2012-01-23 Aktiva 10 122.653
> 18. 2012-01-24 Aktiva 10 122.507
> 19. 2012-01-25 Aktiva 10 122.582
> 20. 2012-01-26 Aktiva 10 122.783
> 21. 2012-01-27 Aktiva 10 122.804
> 22. 2012-01-30 Aktiva 10 122.749
> 23. 2012-01-31 Aktiva 10 122.865
> 24. 2012-02-01 Aktiva 10 123.044
> 25. 2012-02-02 Aktiva 10 123.184
> 26. 2012-02-03 Aktiva 10  123.32
> 27. 2012-02-06 Aktiva 10 123.402
> 28. 2012-02-07 Aktiva 10 123.322
> 29. 2012-02-08 Aktiva 10 123.342
> 30. 2012-02-09 Aktiva 10 123.421
> 31. 2012-02-10 Aktiva 10 123.368
> 32. 2012-02-13 Aktiva 10 123.418
> 33. 2012-02-14 Aktiva 10 123.389
> 34. 2012-02-15 Aktiva 10 123.558
> 35. 2012-02-16 Aktiva 10 123.735
> 36. 2012-02-17 Aktiva 10 123.636
> 37. 2012-02-20 Aktiva 10  123.68
> 38. 2012-02-21 Aktiva 10 123.701
> 39. 2012-02-22 Aktiva 10 123.705
> 40. 2012-02-23 Aktiva 10 123.663
> 41. 2012-02-24 Aktiva 10 123.723
> 42. 2012-02-27 Aktiva 10  123.77
> 43. 2012-02-28 Aktiva 10   123.9
> 44. 2012-02-29 Aktiva 10  123.91
> 45. 2012-03-01 Aktiva 10  123.95
> 46. 2012-03-02 Aktiva 10  124.02
> 47. 2012-03-05 Aktiva 10  123.98
> 48. 2012-03-06 Aktiva 10  123.74
> 49. 2012-03-07 Aktiva 10  123.79
> 50. 2012-03-08 Aktiva 10  123.92
> 51. 2012-03-09 Aktiva 10  124.05

dput(df[1:50,]) data looks like this:

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(954720000, 954806400, 954892800, 
954979200, 955065600, 955324800, 955411200, 955497600, 955584000, 
955670400, 955929600, 956016000, 956102400, 956620800, 956707200, 
956793600, 956880000, 957225600, 957312000, 957398400, 957484800, 
957744000, 957830400, 957916800, 958003200, 958089600, 958348800, 
958435200, 958608000, 958694400, 958953600, 959040000, 959126400, 
959212800, 959299200, 959558400, 959644800, 959731200, 959904000, 
960163200, 960249600, 960336000, 960422400, 960508800, 960854400, 
960940800, 961027200, 961113600, 961372800, 961459200), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), SecurityId = c(45731, 45731, 45731, 
45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 
45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 
45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 
45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 
45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 45731, 
45731, 45731), FundId = c(109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 
109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 
109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 
109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 
109, 109, 109, 109), Symbol = c("AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", 
"AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", 
"AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", 
"AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", 
"AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", 
"AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", 
"AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", 
"AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", 
"AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2", "AI-NORS2"), 
    ISIN = c("NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", 
    "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", 
    "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", 
    "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", 
    "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", 
    "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", 
    "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", 
    "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", 
    "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", 
    "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", 
    "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", 
    "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", 
    "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576", "NO0010089576"), Name = c("ABIF Norge ++", 
    "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", 
    "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", 
    "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", 
    "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", 
    "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", 
    "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", 
    "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", 
    "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", 
    "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", 
    "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", 
    "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", 
    "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", "ABIF Norge ++", 
    "ABIF Norge ++"), NAV = c(100, 99.4291, 93.5061, 96.9827, 
    98.3752, 98.9016, 96.932, 96.6528, 95.5597, 92.9564, 90.4477, 
    91.9742, 94.0813, 94.6611, 95.7128, 94.3541, 96.9792, 98.5621, 
    99.8926, 100.9441, 100.8709, 101.4863, 101.9841, 100.9585, 
    101.6321, 103.3527, 103.3474, 104.5718, 106.1602, 104.2994, 
    103.8382, 103.5229, 101.8999, 103.1289, 101.968, 101.0299, 
    102.4697, 102.1109, 104.3061, 103.2584, 102.2464, 101.8824, 
    102.7758, 103.4881, 103.2249, 103.9476, 103.5058, 104.2614, 
    103.3023, 103.4716), NAVAdj = c(98.149473714552, 97.5891383691156, 
    91.7757450410027, 95.1880096441628, 96.554741065638, 97.0713998952714, 
    95.1382478609895, 94.8642145303785, 93.7913426332048, 91.2362173839938, 
    88.7739415369168, 90.2721932531695, 92.3403008138088, 92.9093714624058, 
    93.9416094774617, 92.6080525781021, 95.1845744125828, 96.7381824320104, 
    98.0440611797826, 99.0761028958911, 99.004257481132, 99.6082693423714, 
    100.096857422522, 99.090236420106, 99.7513712750472, 101.44013111978, 
    101.434929197673, 102.636671353834, 104.195677594316, 102.369312187435, 
    101.916646814664, 101.607181524042, 100.014215565655, 101.220472597607, 
    100.081055357254, 99.1603151443382, 100.57347126688, 100.221310955192, 
    102.375888202174, 101.347576166067, 100.354303492076, 99.9970394077547, 
    100.873906805921, 101.573025507189, 101.314696092373, 102.024022338908, 
    101.590397964037, 102.332015387424, 101.390663785028, 101.556830844026
    ), Dividends = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), CorpAdj = c(1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), DividendAdj = c(0.98149473714552, 
    0.98149473714552, 0.98149473714552, 0.98149473714552, 0.98149473714552, 
    0.98149473714552, 0.98149473714552, 0.98149473714552, 0.98149473714552, 
    0.98149473714552, 0.98149473714552, 0.98149473714552, 0.98149473714552, 
    0.98149473714552, 0.98149473714552, 0.98149473714552, 0.98149473714552, 
    0.98149473714552, 0.98149473714552, 0.98149473714552, 0.98149473714552, 
    0.98149473714552, 0.98149473714552, 0.98149473714552, 0.98149473714552, 
    0.98149473714552, 0.98149473714552, 0.98149473714552, 0.98149473714552, 
    0.98149473714552, 0.98149473714552, 0.98149473714552, 0.98149473714552, 
    0.98149473714552, 0.98149473714552, 0.98149473714552, 0.98149473714552, 
    0.98149473714552, 0.98149473714552, 0.98149473714552, 0.98149473714552, 
    0.98149473714552, 0.98149473714552, 0.98149473714552, 0.98149473714552, 
    0.98149473714552, 0.98149473714552, 0.98149473714552, 0.98149473714552, 
    0.98149473714552), lnDeltaNAV = c(0, -0.00572535863116119, 
    -0.0614181525486561, 0.0365059372732999, 0.0142561276907758, 
    0.00533667668298765, -0.0201157147168702, -0.00288452599160749, 
    -0.011373992683045, -0.027620617044005, -0.0273587829153019, 
    0.016736319832737, 0.0226511991448142, 0.00614384286518277, 
    0.0110488958739232, -0.0142973147308307, 0.0274417964293168, 
    0.0161902838567531, 0.0134088024604093, 0.0104712894394297, 
    -0.000725416873969209, 0.0060823326001147, 0.00489310477802452, 
    -0.0101073774671372, 0.00664988881292139, 0.0167879804789104, 
    -5.12820264839675e-05, 0.0117777882336343, 0.0150753571586755, 
    -0.0176836646173788, -0.00443169090857154, -0.00304107417442001, 
    -0.0158018853966349, 0.0119887032476456, -0.0113206235496355, 
    -0.00924252593779595, 0.0141506324870466, -0.00350766756849463, 
    0.021270367882865, -0.0100952609714282, -0.00984899798499139, 
    -0.00356637951931749, 0.00873070978798651, 0.00690671350197469, 
    -0.00254652723566728, 0.00697682300028468, -0.00425927623174083, 
    0.0072735574356857, -0.00924156609376592, 0.0016375377920701
    ), lnDeltaOSEBX = c(0, -0.00940531538140732, -0.0515228085845063, 
    0.0330841053596203, 0.0149328822530661, 0.00140488772073599, 
    -0.0184601740944386, 0.00262641959218701, -0.012317562508172, 
    -0.0263240283504187, -0.0138437179343693, 0.0132849051679038, 
    0.0210929614810249, 0.0016248841643085, 0.00827607079901416, 
    -0.0154081787503344, 0.0261622502400947, 0.0179854981160581, 
    0.013271853834639, 0.0118876641774017, -0.000609937259577364, 
    0.00136092770291629, 0.00375227676786949, -0.00991727309818735, 
    0.00470404341043462, 0.0178788765076252, 0.000550091704436539, 
    0.015506961679753, 0.0137508866550915, -0.0167880781194372, 
    -0.00746925582682945, -0.00163624416898944, -0.0165229230024071, 
    0.0105430179398134, -0.0133781957394445, -0.00546854351296844, 
    0.00984014548362389, -0.00321159549991012, 0.018852089647897, 
    -0.00986344346201573, -0.0101602069993261, 0.000661533679649828, 
    0.0073117003894172, 0.00344172289439459, 0.00378742002574128, 
    0.0007234081265306, -0.00095362267457233, 0.00833764093971467, 
    -0.000905517713564841, -0.00730795598720579), lnDeltaOBX = c(0, 
    -0.00675924299385855, -0.0446627432412416, 0.0271511087647243, 
    0.0104352836056094, 0.00252750079747255, -0.0139940420412588, 
    0.000443962766651929, -0.0134847680574186, -0.0212769716066035, 
    -0.0129102509389352, 0.0167416215616996, 0.0179482930426307, 
    0.00615727334394656, 0.0110326474282347, -0.0133618870045504, 
    0.0222017092722471, 0.0151286494232705, 0.00551851236591716, 
    0.00800823957119601, -0.00142848216759983, 0.00617540558679863, 
    0.00572868073875021, -0.00951190548323133, 0.00500378510823829, 
    0.0164558409589644, -2.4488196690875e-05, 0.0111775180525235, 
    0.0216079600277741, -0.0195879405922108, -0.00801940591750494, 
    0.00259119504119276, -0.0135284308990071, 0.00875445456788881, 
    -0.0118997124506839, -0.0047675452047562, 0.0104833246950742, 
    -0.0035685318306351, 0.0184672492972027, -0.0092276363398982, 
    -0.0119552952128883, 0.00394764949324067, 0.00666321451700913, 
    0.00669200495886102, 0.00710600824465679, -0.00211320833357309, 
    0.00160644545155453, 0.0127356648288117, -0.00153836093566273, 
    -0.00467729378767778), lnDeltaOSEFX = c(0, -0.0132566852489493, 
    -0.054436017358416, 0.036447582787936, 0.0143346129652224, 
    0.00322243291943547, -0.0202744508590715, 0.00351120943021765, 
    -0.0139984771357593, -0.0264788767234734, -0.0224291179937897, 
    0.0147570608902363, 0.0256818445585978, 0.00382403430885514, 
    0.00892967356250907, -0.0176447368553463, 0.0257512997592757, 
    0.0177749823933526, 0.0117569174284275, 0.0136460053312675, 
    -0.00124573887812041, 0.00116160809454247, 0.00402634234849675, 
    -0.0105042345492476, 0.00589741004413469, 0.0189357154629182, 
    0.000452100549805046, 0.0149796051273769, 0.0122373634579906, 
    -0.0179535473500074, -0.00708298187974066, -0.000441760549906078, 
    -0.0169947891004751, 0.0138275915131079, -0.0149290919606084, 
    -0.00617441051640188, 0.0111232403312256, -0.00372148073099599, 
    0.0226673312134444, -0.00968981475443709, -0.00997237606061496, 
    -0.00060224703743561, 0.0086779720852439, 0.00319008738691462, 
    0.00133857674206705, 0.00058350744660185, -0.00325430504398128, 
    0.00767990023126242, -0.000607277053698674, -0.00564152856083044
    ), SMB = c(0.0123311034288627, 0.00915156609628357, -0.00158716760294442, 
    -0.0297416735452946, 0.0014191924545611, -0.0150755252076274, 
    0.0115701574233579, -0.00111340347515908, -0.00819114157880345, 
    -0.024104652357138, 0.0402172827616449, 0.00534146788916141, 
    -0.0154634888942257, 0.00354035521403617, 0.00206630945718951, 
    0.00110824503543285, 0.00577986123704642, -0.0091511299479988, 
    -0.00628038625739494, 0.00641233515248658, -0.00348433542025252, 
    0.00571653658752371, -0.00108622140744236, -0.00467826333193927, 
    0.0015293960849232, 0.0150302224117192, 0.0128782375422192, 
    0.00182479014151233, 0.0118018051325084, -0.00122505374600254, 
    0.0067581316644394, 0.00289618880797662, -0.00922587897314921, 
    -0.0112790492150875, -0.0131539668848055, -0.00483914410215184, 
    0.00392018158948877, -0.00654011695984795, -0.00245063806434721, 
    0.00390394664204772, -0.0119417973629864, 0.00391466483105893, 
    -0.00907824016648776, 0.00281885664081369, 0.0137050768450805, 
    0.0151027414136372, -0.00635772453077626, 0.0141303322841679, 
    -0.000411054109417454, -0.00821935988613381), HML = c(0.0811601046922382, 
    0.0263351665848042, 0.106475381968986, -0.0717486018918445, 
    -0.013401199905366, -0.0262830431094566, 0.0377662920323366, 
    -0.00983345919969417, 0.0384794311058455, 0.101128024713768, 
    0.0389117895270927, -0.0243149370435034, -0.0579205369141316, 
    -0.0174301787358929, 0.00261970745261295, 0.0318994811019162, 
    -0.0400042937351153, -0.00153694356567032, 0.0233985279797224, 
    -0.0401746710352116, 0.0190299884544687, 0.039648558170685, 
    0.0244504738247621, 0.0198792894699696, -0.00870600396129643, 
    -0.102281854622862, -0.00487726994595788, -0.0062245997679463, 
    0.0103673220988611, 0.0642078211928357, 0.000607234654230467, 
    -0.0371130284191367, 0.0309287156839412, -0.0234612031829678, 
    0.0733878599469245, 0.0385598691553834, -0.0278492201926123, 
    -0.0066708890999078, -0.0448929604242489, -0.0143415360857507, 
    -0.0238935048340895, 0.0108320873597463, -0.00762360971561658, 
    -0.00828199565147488, 0.0305644139491684, -0.0254099474698697, 
    0.0250996171797242, 0.00538982163947071, -0.00210515259916917, 
    -0.0195066162810241), LIQ = c(0.0157034253750779, 0.0227002836975072, 
    0.065738432925917, -0.0552351227361365, -0.020988058634736, 
    -0.0119287058062276, 0.0413731668748464, 0.012718095507565, 
    0.00369068026836507, 0.0276632935575419, 0.0370998398194863, 
    0.000314306564174449, -0.0340165785757102, 0.00816108559328334, 
    0.0196198820076372, 0.0206822207525292, -0.022369198083528, 
    -0.00547122285430531, -0.00349413197881119, 0.0154782104314266, 
    0.000385689216523621, 0.00781858322435598, -0.00871198187764726, 
    0.00431754203466546, -0.00946171019470503, 0.0107870226457883, 
    0.0151864839115862, -0.0116275474872604, -0.00141908832914339, 
    -0.000513165399929121, -0.00989121260626544, 0.00203118199429453, 
    -0.00133920286743205, 0.000513811721746565, -0.00890441247364418, 
    -0.000194479560384646, 0.00132777366732754, 0.0109845718520624, 
    -0.0131579761871903, 0.00169925198332302, -0.0175742369163852, 
    0.000469051062196477, 0.00340342712080001, -0.0105237634528422, 
    -0.000376810706883849, 0.0043542754059329, -0.00861982360414743, 
    0.0192809486833832, -0.0043442441716499, -0.0221072737122197
    ), MOM = c(0.0287454429557529, 0.0134782075274417, 0.00806633703967767, 
    -0.0294639612554887, 0.00283144507570127, -0.0117475999780675, 
    0.0271459089999048, -0.00805275416260212, -0.00491915532340628, 
    0.039267068265006, 0.00133730551324356, -0.00723365456343063, 
    -0.0226409142038954, 0.0145194649631461, 0.00724883603814357, 
    -0.00115205579341722, 0.016500139365733, -0.000185216749684504, 
    -0.00934779411541315, -0.0259092770501304, -0.00880067920625633, 
    0.00598712321696791, -0.000870616235833688, 0.00586781179120599, 
    0.00753842573531934, -0.00391557978990263, 0.0059364572892294, 
    -0.0135728247033562, 0.0132819781153358, 0.00189481246194319, 
    0.0103643573349146, 0.00298287034990829, 0.00989923925491796, 
    -0.0166922330388068, 0.0137537988848887, 0.0201338553207169, 
    -0.00545353385720432, -0.00659043125965345, -0.0233699553489148, 
    -0.0168952251152045, 0.00801157245015491, 0.00310250561711743, 
    -0.00582512011171042, 0.00948774604918234, 0.0156395952714775, 
    0.00142863409832036, 0.0112959563212738, -0.00791703211090294, 
    -0.0068101823373943, -0.000386985037747023)), row.names = c(NA, 
-50L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Hi Nik, it would be a lot easier to help if you provide some of your data with `dput`, such as `dput(df[1:50,])`.

Comment: To calculate the monthly return you just need the product of all daily returns within this month. Is the return in the coloumn "NAV"? Then you have to divide it by 100, cause the returns have to be in the form "1.00", "0.9942" and so on. With ```prod(x)``` you get the product of the daily which is the monthly return.

Comment: Thank you for aswering! Well, it is not really return as NAV is (Net asset value) when the market closed the given date. The point is for each fund to just be listed with the NAV for the last date of the month. 
Example: 
Date 2000-04-30 - NAV 96,76 (or whatever is on that day).

Did this make any sense in clarifying the problem?

Comment: and as to providing some of the data is quite hard as it is 362.811 observations in of 19 variables. I do not either know how to provide a portion of it as requested. I am sorry.

Comment: Hi Nik, that is why I recommended subsetting the data to the first 50 rows. This is a relatively easy thing to do with `dplyr` if you can just provide the data.  `dput(df[1:50,])`

Comment: I am able to run the code to extract the 50 lines of data locally, but I do not know how to share it with you here in this forum. I cannot figure out how to get any data into the original post nor the comment section. Is there a guide I could use to solve the problem?

Comment: @IanCampbell I tried to extract some data and put it in the original post. Does this help in any way?

Comment: @Nik, when you run `dput(df[1:50,])` at the console in RStudio, you'll get something that starts with `structure(`. Copy the entire thing and paste it into your original question surrounded by three backticks (the key that has `~` on it)  on either side.

Comment: @IanCampbell I believe I did this now if you'd like to have another look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `tidyverse` and `lubridate` you can do the following.

You can `group_by` month and then `filter` to show only the last row of data for each month. `arrange` is used to sort by `Date` just in case.

**Edit**: Also `group_by` `year(Date)` in this example. Results updated with new data provided.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  group_by(Name, Year = year(Date), Month = month(Date)) %>%
  arrange(Date) %>%
  filter(NAV == last(NAV))
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 3 x 21
# Groups:   Name, Year, Month [3]
  Date                SecurityId FundId Symbol ISIN  Name       NAV    NAVAdj Dividends CorpAdj DividendAdj   lnDeltaNAV lnDeltaOSEBX   lnDeltaOBX lnDeltaOSEFX
  <dttm>                   <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>  <chr> <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
1 2000-04-28 00:00:00      45731    109 AI-NO… NO00… ABIF…  96.9792  95.18457         0       1   0.9814947  0.02744180   0.02616225   0.02220171   0.02575130 
2 2000-05-31 00:00:00      45731    109 AI-NO… NO00… ABIF… 102.1109 100.2213          0       1   0.9814947 -0.003507668 -0.003211595 -0.003568532 -0.003721481
3 2000-06-20 00:00:00      45731    109 AI-NO… NO00… ABIF… 103.4716 101.5568          0       1   0.9814947  0.001637538 -0.007307956 -0.004677294 -0.005641529
# … with 6 more variables: SMB <dbl>, HML <dbl>, LIQ <dbl>, MOM <dbl>, Year <dbl>, Month <dbl>
```

Comment: Hi Ben! Thank you for the suggestion! This seems to be on to something. It arranges the data mostly like I would like it but it seems to be removing vital data. For example on one mutual fund it is removing all data from its birth 2000-04-03 and instead starting 2003-12-30, meaning we've lost quite a few years. Do you have any thoughts on that?

Comment: Since you have multiple years, you also need to group by Year = year(Date) as well. In a couple hours I can return to this and update answer...

Comment: This did the trick! Thank you for your help. This was amazing.